# ajax load page without cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using this ajax function to reload an html page to a division in web page.

```
<script>
    $('#scene_container').load('scene.html', function () {

                cache: false
            });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="scene_container"></div>
```

But most of the time it loads cached webpage. How to load the original html page?

Comment: You set `cache = false` in the callback function. That does not have any effect on the ajax call. You should use the $.ajax function to disable caching. Or as @maj suggests use a url time parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preventing cache is not available with the load method unless you disable it globally

But you can make sure no data will be loaded from cache by appending  a time parameter to the request URL

```
url = "scene.html";
url += '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

To control caching on a per-request basis, you need to use a more complex function like `$.ajax()` .

Insert this at the top of your script:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

[**MANUAL**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

ANother way is to use an unique id like this to the end of the url:

```
$('#scene_container').load('scene.html?uid'+uniqueId());
```

Comment: As per docs `Its use is not recommended.` Also, it will disable cache for all ajax request.

Comment: I added that code. If the problem comes again I'll get back to you. Thank you for the quick response.